# Returning Json to a user if an error occurs in global.asax Application_Start ()

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I need to show a user what kind error happens on my server using json format. And I've already successfully made this with the help of action filters.

But if an exception happens outside of the user's (I mean web-client) request (for example in `Application_Start()` method) then user making any request will get an html page showing error info.

Server tries to start every request (`Application_Start` is called every request), but request itself is not processed properly and error page is shown.

`Exception` in `Application_Start` is caught by `Application_Error` method. But I don't understand how to process it properly.

`Request` object is null in this case because there is no any `Request` when application calls method `Application_Start()`.

Is there any way to send user **Json** info about error when MVC application has an exception in `Application_Start` method?

Thanks!

Comment: teo van kot, thanks for editing

Comment: `Application_Start` is *not* called every request. Beside, if you're having an exception in `Global.asax` it most probably will be a fatal error that the user shouldn't know or care about, formatting it as JSON should be your least concern in that case.

Comment: yes, when there were no exceptions in it. In my case an exception (doesn't matter what) happens in `Application_Start`. And my application can't start because of it. When user makes the next request IIS (I think so) tries to raise up my application and that's why `Application_Start` method is called again.

Comment: 'formatting it as JSON should be your least concern on that case.' You're probably right

Comment: **1**. I guess you'll have to fix the problem and make sure your application bootstraps without errors. **2.** In case error does occur, you can write some code in `Application_Error` to redirect the user to another (preferably static) page like `error.html`.

Comment: Also the requirement "always return error as json" smells like you should be using Web API project rather than MVC.

Comment: Yes, It is really an MVC but more like WebAPI. Don't ask me why *)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with setting of a default redirect in my web.config.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/errors/500.json"></customErrors>
```

And created 500.json file with static content.